# Calling IEnumerable overload of DisplayNameFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, razor

This works for grabbing the headers(**NOT VALUES**):

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeModel>
...
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SomeModelProperty)</th>
```

Which if SomeModelProperty were:

```
[Display(Name = "An Excellent Header")]
SomeModelProperty { get; set; }
```

Then it would display "An Excellent Header" in the header `th` element.

You would think this wouldn't work because the model is IEnumerable, which wouldn't have a m.SomeModelProperty, but it works because HtmlHelper has a `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>>` such that the parameter of the lambda is `TModel`, not `IEnumerable<TModel>`.  Since this just uses metadata, there is no need for an item from the collection.  (Although intellisense on `m.` will lie to you and make you think it's a collection).  I'm not sure when this cool overload was added, but is quite handy for Index.cshtml and does away with funky things like `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => @Model.FirstOrDefault().SomeModelProperty)` which I want to avoid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833697(v=vs.108).aspx

However, I can't figure out how to get this to work when my model is not IEnumerable, but instead contains IEnumerable as a property, such as:

```
public class SomeList
{
   public List<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }
   public int Page { get; set; }
   public DateTime CurrentAsOf { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping to be explicit with the generic type parameters, but I think the type parameters are specified by the engine that trickles down from the HtmlHelper created with the page.  Can I declare a new HtmlHelper in the page, or somehow specify the type parameters explicitly?

Index.cshtml:

```
@model SomeList
//No idea how to do this:
@Html.DisplayNameFor<IEnumerable<SomeModel>>(m => m.SomeModelProperty)
```

Comment: In your loop code in your Razor file, you could check if it is the **first** element in the loop, and output the `<thead>` section using the `DisplayNameFor` calls.  This `if` would be before the part where you output the data in a `tr`.

Comment: Yes I've used these types of workarounds am hoping to move away from that now that DisplayNameFor supports getting metadata from IEnumerable

Comment: This question has a good and working solution (accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807869/displaynamefor-from-listobject-in-model

Comment: @Ixa Technically that question is a duplicate of this question since mine came first, but oh well.  Nice find :) Voted to close mine.

Comment: Note that if you some property is IEnumerable, rather than IList, you can access it via
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SomeModels.First().Item)

NB: First() is not actually run, so does not throw an exception if SomeModels is empty

Answer (score 44):

Another similar workaround that works even if there are no rows could be:

```
...
@{var dummy = Model.FirstOrDefault(); }
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.SomeModelProperty)
        </th>
...
```

Comment: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<CHFN.Models.CaseHealthareProviderRepresentativeElement,int>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CHFN.Models.CaseHealthareProviderRepresentativeElement>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<CHFN.Models.CaseHealthareProviderRepresentativeElement,int>>)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CHFN.Models.CaseHealthareProviderRepresentativeElement>,int>...

Comment: same problem as Oleg Sh...

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I have exactly the same issue because I am using ViewModels so I have a ViewModel with an IEnumerable of actual objects as a property.

I did come across this post where if you check the answer the guy has created his own HTMLHelper for it to solve this issue http://forums.asp.net/t/1783733.aspx.  His version is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayColumnNameFor<TModel, TClass, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, IEnumerable<TClass> model, 
    Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    name = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(
        () => Activator.CreateInstance<TClass>(), typeof(TClass), name);

    return new MvcHtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
}
```

You have to pass two arguments enumeration and expression rather than the normal just expression so you may prefer @franz answer.  I can't see there being anyway round having to pass 2 arguments since it needs to know which property of the view model you are applying the expression to.