# PagedList MVC does not contain a definition for PagedListPager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I don't know why PageCount,PageNumber and PageListPager doesn't contain a definintion or could not be found. It's asking if I'm missing a using directive or an assembly reference but I have it in my user controller.

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
 to 
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter }) )
```

Note: IMAGES AND CODE BELOW ARE ONLY FOR REFERENCE

[image: Database Error]

[image: Visual Studio error]

Controllers\UserController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL;
using PagedList;

namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private IssueContext db = new IssueContext();

        //
        // GET: /User/

        public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var users = from s in db.Users
                           select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                       || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    users = users.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                default:  // Name ascending 
                    users = users.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Views\User\Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}

<h2>Users</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)  
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

<table>
     <tr>
        <th>
 @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
 to 
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter }) )
```

Comment: Have you included the `using` statements in your view? And you model needs to be `@model IPagedList<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User>` (not `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and I got this error. Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IPagedList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Line 32:     
Line 33:     
Line 34:     public class _Page_Views_User_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IPagedList<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User>> {
Line 35:         
Line 36: #line hidden

Comment: You cannot just change the original question (and I have rolled back your changes). You need both `@using PagedList;` and `@using PagedList.Mvc;`

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IPagedList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).Line 40:     public class _Page_Views_User_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IPagedList<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User>> {

Comment: The message is self explanatory - your missing the correct `using` statements. Did you add both as per my last comment.

Comment: Yes it works ! Thanks! I thought Visual Studio puts in using statements as defaults when i install packages to that solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`PageCount`, `PageNumber` etc are properties of `IPagedList<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to change the model in the view to use `IPagedList<T>`, and include the relevant using statements.

```
@using PagedList; // add
@using PagedList.Mvc; //add
@model IPagedList<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User> // change
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}
.....
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference using IEnumerable and IPagedList??

Comment: [IEnumerable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is the base class in the .NET framework for enumerating collections. It does not contain any properties. [IPagedList<T>](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/IPagedList.cs) is an interface in the `PagedList.Mvc` assembly that extends `IEnumerable<T>` to add additional properties for `PageCount` etc. `IPagedList<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>` but `IEnumerable<T>` is not `IPagedList<T>`

Comment: What gives with removing the accept/vote? Are you still having problems?

Comment: I had multiple screens on the same webpage so I removed it and did it again to make sure I upvoted. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No need for `;` with the `@using` in `cshtml`, and no need for `@using PagedList` either or order change, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You missing **using** of **PagedList** and **PagedList.Mvc** , as others told you.

What I can add, better add using of namespaces in file **Views/Web.Config** instead. This will allow you to use namespaces **PagedList** and **PagedList.Mvc** in all Views, and shorten your code. Example:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="PagedList" />        <!--Add this line-->
      <add namespace="PagedList.MVC" />    <!--Add this line-->
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

And no more need to use **using** in everyone view/cshtml

```
@* @using PagedList; // No more need of this, can delete this line *@
@* @using PagedList.Mvc; // No more need of this, can delete this line *@
@model IPagedList<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User> // change
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}
.....
```

This is especially valuable, when you have a big project, it will shorten your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add `@using PagedList` and `@using PagedList.Mvc` don't have to precede the `@model` directive. Instead just use `PagedList.IPagedList` instead of just `IPagedList`.

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User>
@using PagedList.Mvc
```

Bonus time save: if you were using `DisplayNameFor` in your view (like `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDateTime)`, then you'd want to change that to:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().CreatedDateTime)
```

(`.FirstOrDefault()` was added because `IPagedList` changes the semantics. See [Using @Html.DisplayNameFor() with PagedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929311/using-html-displaynamefor-with-pagedlist)).