# ViewModel does Not contain definition for Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to bind two `UserManager` `Feedback` model with one view  but i am facing problem in view that a view does not contain any definition for email...here is my all code

```
public  class FeedbackMixModel
    {

        public List<UserManager> allUserManagers { get; set; }

        public List<Feedback> allfeedbacks { get; set; }

    }
```

controller==>>>

```
  var user = db.UserManagers.ToList();
            var feedbacks = db.Feedbacks.ToList();

            var Model = new FeedbackMixModel
            {
                allUserManagers =user,
                allfeedbacks=feedbacks
            };

            return View(Model);
```

view==>>

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.FeedbackMixModel


<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

        <!-- Main content -->


            <table class="pretty" id="dt">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th >
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentStorage)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MaxStorage)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastLoginMonth)
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     @foreach (var item in Model.allUserManagers)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentStorage)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaxStorage)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastLoginMonth)
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

i am totally confused how to solve this... where Email define in `UserManager` Class how i can access if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Your `FeedbackMixModel` does not have an `Email` property. Nor does it have `CurrentStorage`, `MaxStorage` or `LastLoginMonth`. Where are these properties located?

Comment: these properties are located in userManager class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual `FeedbackMixModel` Model itself doesn't have a definition for the properties that you intend to use for your header :

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentStorage)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MaxStorage)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastLoginMonth)
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Your existing Model only contains two properties : `allUserManagers` and `allFeedbacks`, so it doesn't know what `Email` or some of the other properties you are referencing are. Based on your current code, these appear to be actual properties of your `UserManager` objects and not your actual `FeedbackMixModel` class.

You could consider hard-coding your header to express these properties :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
          Email
        </th>
        <th>
          Current Storage
        </th>
        <th>
          Max Storage
        </th>
        <th>
          Last Login Month
        </th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
```

or you could attempt to target the first element in your collection similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808067/557445):

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.allUserManagers[0].Email)
        </th>
        <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.allUserManagers[0].CurrentStorage)
        </th>
        <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.allUserManagers[0].MaxStorage)
        </th>
        <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.allUserManagers[0].LastLoginMonth)
        </th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: this is the view model contain two others model UserManager and Feedback Email and other properties are defind in UserManager Class is there anyy method to access them???

Comment: You could use an approach similar to the one provided that still uses the `DisplayNameFor()` helper to attempt to resolve the appropriate property names.