# ASP.NET MVC. How use DisplayNameFor in order to create a table heading and body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, displayfor

How get a property display name using `DisplayNameFor()`to build a table header. for instance:

```
   @model IEnumerable<Item>
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(? => ?.prop1)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(? => ?.prop2)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(? => ?.prop3)</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (Item item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.prop1)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.prop2)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.prop3)</td>
                </tr>
            }    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

what should I write in the question marks?

Comment: Using `LabelFor()` is not appropriate (it generates a label that is intended to associated with a form control, but you have many). Use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.prop1)`

Comment: So what problem are you now having? (see the code in my previous comment)

Comment: Model is a IEnumerable<Item> not the Item class..

Comment: Yes I know. Try it :) (`DisplayNameFor()` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx) for `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've never noticed this overload! I hope you'll have time to post this as an answer so others can find it. There's a lot more of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20808067/4270650) around.

Comment: @WillRay, The answer in that link is correct and necessary because the `model` is not `IEnumerable<T>` (its a model that contains a property that is `IEnumerable<T>`) - I'm trying to find a suitable dupe, but if not I'll add an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DisplayNameFor()` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7BSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7B%60%600%7D%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D%29) that accepts `IEnumerable<T>` so it simply needs to be

```
<td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.prop1)</td>
```

Note that this only works where the the model is `Enumerable<T>` (in you case `@model IEnumerable<Item>`).

**But will not work if the model was an object containing a proeprty which was `IEnumerable<T>`**.

For example, the following will not work

```
<td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MyCollection.prop1)</td>
```

and it would need to be

```
<td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MyCollection.FirstOrDefault().prop1)</td>
```

which will work even if the collection contains no items.

Side note: Under some circumstances, you may initially get a razor error, but you can ignore it. Once you run the app, that error will disappear.

Comment: I actually liked your answer more than mine, I didn't know about that overload. If `MyCollection` is an IEnumerable, then you'd need to use something like `m.MyCollection.First().prop1`, wouldn't you? Because since it wouldn't be an array, your couldn't use `MyCollection[0]`. Is that right?

Comment: @Alisson, Your right (the indexer would be for a property which is `IList<T>`) - have updated.

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this:

```
   @model IEnumerable<Item>
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(i => i.First().prop1)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(i => i.First().prop2)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(i => i.First().prop3)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (Item item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.prop1)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.prop2)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.prop3)</td>
                </tr>
            }    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It may look like you are actually getting the first item of the IEnumerable, but you are not.

Since the parameter you are passing to `DisplayFor()` is just an Expression Tree, it won't execute IEnumerable's `First()` method at all, internally `DisplayFor()` will only check for the passed type (the parameter's type) to use reflection and build a display for it.

Comment: What if the the list was empty?

Comment: @DanielSantos it still works, because the `DisplayFor` will not try to get some object instance from the Expression Tree, it will only analyze its metadata in order to build a display for it. The `i.First().prop1` is not going to be called there, that's why there is no problem using like that. Try it.

Comment: should those be <th> tags in the <thead> instead of <td>

Comment: You're right, I just copied the sample code from the question and didn't pay attention to that. Fixed it, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the model to an `IList<Item>` or `Item[]` you can do this:

```
   @model IList<Item>
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x[0].prop1)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x[0].prop2)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x[0].prop3)</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        ...
    </table>
```

Comment: This would fail if the item list is empty. Better add condition before creating the table.

Comment: @AnkitVijay the lambda expression is not executed, only analyzed.

Comment: I could be wrong about the list, however, I feel we would still execute all these lines of code when it is not needed. If condition can save us on that?

Comment: @MaxToro that's why I think there is no need to use `IList<Item>` or `Item[]`. The code will just analyze the expression to get metadata and build a display. It would work even if the `IEnumerable` was null. Actually I think this should work even with a null model, since the code won't get an object instance from the expression tree at all.