# What does the model parameter mean in case of strongly typed container model

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I don't quite understand the following [strongly typed models syntax](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html#strongly-typed-models-and-the-model-keyword):

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Why do we access the `Genre` property like this?

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
```

I thought that the `model` here refers to the whole container:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: I believe [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029941/asp-net-mvc-how-use-displaynamefor-in-order-to-create-a-table-heading-and-body) will answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to execute the code you have shown? I don't think it will work. It looks like the tutorial you have linked shows you a div (using yellow highlights) to clear up the difference between  `@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie` and `@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>`.

So the correct way would be:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
            </td>
         @* ... *@
        </tr>
}
```

Comment: Nah, it works. And I'm strongly suggest you to take a look at the link I provided again