# confused with html helper in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper

I have a view model class

```
public class NewCustomerViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<MembershipType> MembershipType { get; set; }
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a Customers controller with New() action method :

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var membershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList();
    var viewModel = new NewCustomerViewModel
    {
        MembershipType = membershipTypes
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

the view is :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers"))
{ 
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Customer.Birthdate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Customer.Birthdate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(e => e.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter, new { @class = "checkbox" }) Subscribed To Newsletter?
        </label>
    </div>
```

For example, what's this for?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Customer.Name, ...)
```

we just have an empty Customer instance at the moment and we are trying to get the name?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Im not fully understanding your question, can you please try and refine what youre saying and be explicit with a question. Also, let us know what you're expecting to happen

Comment: You may need to create a new Customer object in you model, At present it is null.

Comment: *"I am not quite confused with html helper"* ... well, that's good, right?

Comment: @SimonPrice  sorry, I have rephrase my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807869/displaynamefor-from-listobject-in-model) a while ago.

Though you are never instantiating `Customer`, the object is defined and the engine is able to build your view for it.

On postback, the ModelBinder will instantiate a new `Customer` and try to populate it back up from your form values.  The web is stateless, so it doesn't matter if you sent in a pre-populated `Customer` object or an empty one when building the form, on postback ASP.NET can only construct it from what's in the form.

Comment: So there are two Customer objects? One empty, one with form values as properties? It is just weird to me for just have a null Customer object doing nothing?

Comment: on the `GET` request, there's an object that contains a null `Customer` object, but still has metadata about the `Customer`.  On postback, the ModelBinder will instantiate the `Customer` object and attempt to fill it in for your controller.

Comment: The html helper (`@Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Customer.Name, ...`) is getting the metadata about the `Customer.Name` object to create labels for that input