# How to convert DisplayNameFor as hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to convert/ use DisplayNameFor as hyperlink which redirects to next page

Here is my code :

```html
 @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Record>
 @using (Html.BeginForm())

 {
      @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id).ToHtmlString(), "ADDPage", new { model=> model.id })
}
```

Getting error at new { model=> model.id }. How do I get id as pass it into this new { model=> model.id }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't getting an error at `Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)`? Your model is an `IEnumerable<T>` which doesn't have an `id` property.

Presumably, you are trying to loop through the items in your model, in which case it would look something like this:

```
@foreach(var record in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => record.id), "ADDPage", new { record.id })
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right  getting an error at Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id). .
Without using for loop can I not directly get the ID ?

Comment: I need to use it as like a header. But adding foreach loop i get N number of IDs

Comment: @Hob See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807869/displaynamefor-from-listobject-in-model